# How do I optimize SQL query with multiple left joins

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have the log table to store user web page views.

The table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE page_views (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    user_id integer,
    ip character varying(255),
    url character varying,
    title character varying(255),
    user_agent character varying(255),
    created_at timestamp(0) with time zone
);

CREATE SEQUENCE analytics_id_seq
  START WITH 1
  INCREMENT BY 1
  NO MINVALUE
  NO MAXVALUE
  CACHE 1;

ALTER SEQUENCE analytics_id_seq OWNED BY page_views.id;

ALTER TABLE ONLY page_views ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT nextval('analytics_id_seq'::regclass);

ALTER TABLE ONLY page_views ADD CONSTRAINT page_views_pk PRIMARY KEY (id);

CREATE INDEX page_views_url_title_index ON page_views USING btree (url, title);

CREATE INDEX page_views_user_id_index ON page_views USING btree (user_id);
```

I want to pull the information about each page views count.

- Total count
- Count in this week
- Count in the last week
- Count in this month
- Count in the last month

The pages must be grouped by url and title.

The query I wrote looks like this:

```
SELECT count(page_views.id) AS "total_count", "page_views"."url", "page_views"."title", "current_week"."count" AS "current_week_count", "prev_week"."count" AS "prev_week_count", "current_month"."count" AS "current_month_count", "prev_month"."count" AS "prev_month_count" FROM "page_views"

LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT count(id) AS "count", "url", "title" FROM "page_views"
  WHERE (extract(year from page_views.created_at) = extract(year from current_date)) AND (extract(week from page_views.created_at) = extract(week from current_date))
  GROUP BY "url", "title"
) "current_week" ON page_views.url = current_week.url AND page_views.title = current_week.title

LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT count(id) AS "count", "url", "title" FROM "page_views"
  WHERE (extract(year from page_views.created_at) = extract(year from current_date)) AND (extract(week from page_views.created_at) = extract(week from current_date - interval '1 week'))
  GROUP BY "url", "title"
) "prev_week" ON page_views.url = prev_week.url AND page_views.title = prev_week.title

LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT count(id) AS "count", "url", "title" FROM "page_views"
  WHERE (extract(year from page_views.created_at) = extract(year from current_date)) AND (extract(month from page_views.created_at) = extract(month from current_date))
  GROUP BY "url", "title"
) "current_month" ON page_views.url = current_month.url AND page_views.title = current_month.title

LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT count(id) AS "count", "url", "title" FROM "page_views"
  WHERE (extract(year from page_views.created_at) = extract(year from current_date)) AND (extract(month from page_views.created_at) = extract(month from current_date - interval '1 month'))
  GROUP BY "url", "title"
) "prev_month" ON page_views.url = prev_month.url AND page_views.title = prev_month.title


GROUP BY "page_views"."url", "page_views"."title", "current_week_count", "prev_week_count", "current_month_count", "prev_month_count"

ORDER BY "total_count" DESC

LIMIT 25
```

At first only total count was needed. Adding index to url and title pair increased the query perfomance. But now with that additional count the execution time is big again.

Average query execution time: 17 seconds.

Page load with that query takes about 45 seconds (that query executed one more time to get total count of records).

I think the left joins is the reason of that, because 5 single queries are executing pretty fast.

EXPLAIN ANALYZE gives the following output:

```
QUERY PLAN
Limit (cost=93923.09..93923.16 rows=25 width=136) (actual time=18779.707..18779.722 rows=25 loops=1)
-> Sort (cost=93923.09..93961.56 rows=15387 width=136) (actual time=18779.701..18779.707 rows=25 loops=1)
Sort Key: (count(page_views.id))
Sort Method: top-N heapsort Memory: 21kB
-> GroupAggregate (cost=90257.65..93488.88 rows=15387 width=136) (actual time=16884.156..18768.617 rows=17778 loops=1)
-> Sort (cost=90257.65..90642.32 rows=153868 width=136) (actual time=16711.488..18631.405 rows=153879 loops=1)
Sort Key: page_views.url, page_views.title, (count(page_views_1.id)), (count(page_views_2.id)), (count(page_views_3.id)), (count(page_views_4.id))
Sort Method: external merge Disk: 20968kB
-> Hash Left Join (cost=44767.14..55958.90 rows=153868 width=136) (actual time=3531.133..4874.422 rows=153879 loops=1)
Hash Cond: (((page_views.url)::text = (page_views_4.url)::text) AND ((page_views.title)::text = (page_views_4.title)::text))
-> Hash Left Join (cost=33575.36..43613.10 rows=153868 width=128) (actual time=2730.681..3609.524 rows=153879 loops=1)
Hash Cond: (((page_views.url)::text = (page_views_3.url)::text) AND ((page_views.title)::text = (page_views_3.title)::text))
-> Hash Left Join (cost=22383.57..31267.29 rows=153868 width=120) (actual time=2103.744..2738.826 rows=153879 loops=1)
Hash Cond: (((page_views.url)::text = (page_views_2.url)::text) AND ((page_views.title)::text = (page_views_2.title)::text))
-> Hash Left Join (cost=11191.79..18921.49 rows=153868 width=112) (actual time=1157.999..1538.455 rows=153879 loops=1)
Hash Cond: (((page_views.url)::text = (page_views_1.url)::text) AND ((page_views.title)::text = (page_views_1.title)::text))
-> Seq Scan on page_views (cost=0.00..6575.68 rows=153868 width=104) (actual time=0.027..91.389 rows=153879 loops=1)
-> Hash (cost=11191.77..11191.77 rows=1 width=108) (actual time=1157.958..1157.958 rows=3072 loops=1)
Buckets: 1024 Batches: 1 Memory Usage: 581kB
-> HashAggregate (cost=11191.75..11191.76 rows=1 width=104) (actual time=1150.583..1153.481 rows=3072 loops=1)
-> Seq Scan on page_views page_views_1 (cost=0.00..11191.72 rows=4 width=104) (actual time=573.709..1105.539 rows=21945 loops=1)
Filter: ((date_part('year'::text, created_at) = date_part('year'::text, (('now'::cstring)::date)::timestamp without time zone)) AND (date_part('week'::text, created_at) = date_part('week'::text, (('now'::cstring)::date)::timestamp without time zone)))
Rows Removed by Filter: 131934
-> Hash (cost=11191.77..11191.77 rows=1 width=108) (actual time=945.707..945.707 rows=4093 loops=1)
Buckets: 1024 Batches: 1 Memory Usage: 756kB
-> HashAggregate (cost=11191.75..11191.76 rows=1 width=104) (actual time=938.578..941.428 rows=4093 loops=1)
-> Seq Scan on page_views page_views_2 (cost=0.00..11191.72 rows=4 width=104) (actual time=291.257..889.204 rows=29781 loops=1)
Filter: ((date_part('year'::text, created_at) = date_part('year'::text, (('now'::cstring)::date)::timestamp without time zone)) AND (date_part('week'::text, created_at) = date_part('week'::text, (('now'::cstring)::date - '7 days'::interval))))
Rows Removed by Filter: 124098
-> Hash (cost=11191.77..11191.77 rows=1 width=108) (actual time=626.909..626.909 rows=3072 loops=1)
Buckets: 1024 Batches: 1 Memory Usage: 581kB
-> HashAggregate (cost=11191.75..11191.76 rows=1 width=104) (actual time=621.925..623.915 rows=3072 loops=1)
-> Seq Scan on page_views page_views_3 (cost=0.00..11191.72 rows=4 width=104) (actual time=284.954..598.724 rows=21945 loops=1)
Filter: ((date_part('year'::text, created_at) = date_part('year'::text, (('now'::cstring)::date)::timestamp without time zone)) AND (date_part('month'::text, created_at) = date_part('month'::text, (('now'::cstring)::date)::timestamp without time zone)))
Rows Removed by Filter: 131934
-> Hash (cost=11191.77..11191.77 rows=1 width=108) (actual time=800.412..800.412 rows=10871 loops=1)
Buckets: 1024 Batches: 4 (originally 1) Memory Usage: 1025kB
-> HashAggregate (cost=11191.75..11191.76 rows=1 width=104) (actual time=776.933..785.074 rows=10871 loops=1)
-> Seq Scan on page_views page_views_4 (cost=0.00..11191.72 rows=4 width=104) (actual time=0.028..680.576 rows=84245 loops=1)
Filter: ((date_part('year'::text, created_at) = date_part('year'::text, (('now'::cstring)::date)::timestamp without time zone)) AND (date_part('month'::text, created_at) = date_part('month'::text, (('now'::cstring)::date - '1 mon'::interval))))
Rows Removed by Filter: 69634
Total runtime: 19112.027 ms
```

Currently there are 153 868 records on the production server.
On my development server there are only 3 463 records and the query executes pretty fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do that in a single query:

```
SELECT url, 
       title, 
       count(*) as total_count,
       count(case when date_trunc('week', current_date) = date_trunc('week', created_at) then 1 else null end) as current_week_count,
       count(case when date_trunc('week', current_date - interval '1 week') = date_trunc('week', created_at) then 1 else null end) as prev_week_count,
       count(case when date_trunc('month', current_date) = date_trunc('month', created_at) then 1 else null end) as this_month_count,
       count(case when date_trunc('month', current_date - interval '1' month) = date_trunc('month', created_at) then 1 else null end) as prev_month_count
FROM page_views
GROUP BY url, title
```

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by "... you get the picture ..."?

Comment: @arogachev: I was too lazy to repeat the expression for the previous month as this is exactly the same as the other expressions just with a different comparison.

Comment: Tested it, the error appears: ERROR: syntax error at or near "when" LINE 4: count(when date_trunc('week', current_date) = date_tr...

Comment: Sorry, typo. Corrected